# Importing variables from other programs

Tags: python, variables

TLDR; i need file 2 (CCST_SUP.py) to import 2 variables from file 1 (CCST_Multi_Simp.py) without asking for the repeat variable input in file 1.

Im trying to write a program that can run several Collatz equations at once, for this to be useful I need the adjacent programs to start where the last one stops while running side by side. I decided that to do this I would run a starter program that would open the script file and pull the variables from the starter, these variables would increase with each iteration of the program and the hope was to encrinite with each program running side by side. however when I run the starter and enter how may iterations I want it reruns the starter program before running the algorithm. I might be missing something stupid simple I only learned python just for this so my knowledge is limited and searched proved fruitless.

```
#CCST_Multi_Simp.py
r0 = int(input('how many times to repeat program: '))
r1 = 0
Start = 1
Rep = 1000
code = "start cmd /k python C:\\Users\\anon\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\CCST\\CCST-SUP.py"
import os
while r0 != r1 or r1 > r0:
    os.system(code)
    Start += 1000
    r1 += 1
```

```
from CCST_Multi_Simp import *



#First input value is your starting seed
z = int(CCST_Multi_Simp.Start)

#Second input is how many seeds after you want to test
#Set r1 to -1 to test indefinatly (do not reccomend)
#best to set r1 to 1 for higher numbers (youll see why if you dont know already)
r1 = int(CCST_Multi_Simp.Rep)

x = z
y = 0
r0 = 0

#line break
print(" ")

#incase some smoothbrain doesnt read that i need two inputs
if r1:
    print()
    print("ready")
    print()
else:
    r1 = 1
    print()
    print("ready")
    print()

#Runs the loop for the number of seeds you want to test
while r0 != r1:
    #used to determine which formula to use
    w = float(x % 2)
    #determines when to end testing
    if x != 1:
        #calculations for even numbers
        if w == 0:
            
            y = x / 2
            x = y
            
        else:
            #calculation for odd numbers
            
            y = x * 3 + 1
            x = y
            
    else:
        #sets up for the next seed
        print("<----------------------------->")
        print("End Of Seed", z)
        import time
        t = time.localtime()
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
        print(current_time)
        
        z += 1
        x = z
        r0 += 1
#past here is formatting for the end of program
```

Detailed notes are because I copy and pasted from this project I posted from another site which simply ran the designated seeds replacing the variables I want to import for `input()` the reason why I don't continue with `input()` is because it would be tedious entering both values 15+ times

I tried importing the variables a couple of different ways including `from [file] import *` and simply `import [File]` the variables are importing properly I just don't know how to not run the starter program when I do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Oops... you are making a confusion between *importing* a symbol from a module and *passing* parameter to an child process.

`import` only performs the first task: when you split a program in many source files (or use library packages), the main module *imports* the others ones and then access their symbols through the import machinery *inside the same process*.

Here you have one main *process* lauching child processes. As the processes are distinct one cannot access any variable in another one. A quick and dirty fix is to just pass the relevant values at launch time and get them in the child processes from the command line:

In laucher program:

```
...
Start = 1
Rep = 1000
# add relevant values at the end of the command line
code = f"start cmd /k python C:\\Users\\anon\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\CCST\\CCST-SUP.py {Start} {Rep}"
...
```

And in child program:

```
import sys

#First input value is your starting seed
z = int(sys.argv[1])

#Second input is how many seeds after you want to test
#Set r1 to -1 to test indefinatly (do not reccomend)
#best to set r1 to 1 for higher numbers (youll see why if you dont know already)
r1 = int(sys.argv[2])
...
```

But using `os.system` is not among the best practices... You should at least use the `subprocess` module which gives finer control on the child processes or look for the `multiprocessing` module as your child processes are only Python modules.

Comment: I think I got it but can you use stupid terms just to make sure. I'm not up with the lingo I usually just mess around with HTML until I figure out how to do cool things.